# Есть ли гарантии, что блок catch() поймать исключение, брошенное из деструктора, который был вызван при выходе из блока try?

Tags: c++, исключения

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
try
{
    Object object;
    // ...
}
catch (...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, что произойдет, если деструктор `Object` бросить исключение?

Будет ли считаться, что исключение возникло внутри блока `try`? Произойдет ли корректный перехват такого исключения блоком `catch()`? Что по этому поводу говорит `Стандарт`?

PS. Да, я знаю, что деструкторам не следует генерировать исключения, но все же.

Comment: согласно стандарту нельзя бросать исключение в конструкторе. Точно не помню, но это либо запрещено, либо UB

Comment: Может вам попробовать сначала самому заглядывать в стандарт прежде чем задавать такие вопросы?

Comment: по умолчанию сейчас деструкторы неявно помечены как noexcept (если только специально не стараться этого избежать). а бросание исключения в таких функциях - останов программы. поэтому, не будет оно перехвачено catch блоком.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь (может, и ошибаюсь :)), но в этом случае будет вызван обработчик `terrminate()`.

Comment: ну почти, std::terminate (там одна r). Но можно попробовать что то сделать с terminate_handler

Comment: Может быть, кто-нибудь знает примерное место `Стандарта`, в котором говорится о ситуации, которую я описал? Я попытался найти сам, но 1700 страниц - это реально много, даже если бы `Стандарт` был написан на русском.